# i am getting the same output for all types of inputs pls suggest some way to solve this issue

Tags: python, twitter, analysis, sentiment-analysis

This is a code to perform sentiment analysis on a particular word and then gives a positive or negative feedback.

ERRORS:-
1)I am getting the same output for all types of inputs pls suggest some way to solve this issue.
2)I am not able to extract tweets particular to the date added.

```
import tweepy
import textblob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

api_key = '***************'
api_key_secret = '***************'
access_token = '***************'
access_token_secret = '***************'

authenticator = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
authenticator.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(authenticator, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

crypto_currency = "Dodgecoin"

search= f'#(crypto_currency) -filter:retweets lang:en'

tweet_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search, tweet_mode='extended').items(100)

tweets = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_cursor]

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Tweets'])

for _, row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('https\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('#\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('@\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['tweets'] = re.sub('\\n', '', row['Tweets'])

tweets_df['Polarity'] = tweets_df['Tweets'].map(lambda tweet: textblob.TextBlob(tweet).sentiment.polarity)
tweets_df['Result'] = tweets_df['Polarity'].map(lambda pol: '+' if pol > 0 else '-')

positive = tweets_df[tweets_df.Result == '+'].count()['Tweets']
negative = tweets_df[tweets_df.Result == '-'].count()['Tweets']

langs = ['Positive', 'Negative']
students = [positive,negative]
a=plt.bar(langs,students)
a[0].set_color('g')
a[1].set_color('r')

plt.xlabel("Tweet Sentiment")
plt.ylabel("No. of Tweets")
plt.title("Sentiment Analysis")
plt.legend

plt.show()
```

Comment: A StackOverflow question is better if it asks just one thing. (And your second question about dates sounds like it might be specific to the "tweepy" API, so best to ask at that project, perhaps?).

Comment: For your main question, it might help get some answers if you show what the problematic output of the script is.  Even better would be to make a fully reproducible example, by pasting in an array of example sentences as `tweets`... that might also discover your bug. E.g. if you have 100 sentences, but they are all the same string, then they will all give the same sentiment :-)